# A Preceded By B, so which comes first?

Tags: verbs

I was reading a technical requirement documentation and it says:

> A Save Event preceded by the user un-checking the "Active" check box...

So does it mean that they un-check the "Active" check box and then they Save?

Comment: What do you think it means? _Hint_: Look at the word *preceded* and especially _"pre"_. What do you say is the use of _pre_ here?

Comment: This is a good example of a useless application of the passive; _`A` precedes `B`_ is clear and self-demonstrating in the active. Passivize it and you confuse the effect and the meaning, like printing the word `YELLOW` in red type.

Comment: It rather depends on the rest of the sentence and context, if it's something like *A save event does this one thing. A save event preceded by the user unchecking the "Active" checkbox does this other thing* then it seems more natural to keep talking about 'save events' and use the passive. But if it's in isolation, or the user is expected to follow the operations in order, then the passive is less clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If B precedes A (i.e. B comes before A) then A is preceded by B.

Therefore in your example the user un-checking the "Active" box precedes the save event. So they un-check the box and then they Save.